# selecting elements from distinct jquery form objects

Tags: jquery, forms

I have *x* number of form all with the class `productForm`.
Each of these forms has an hidden input tag with the value of the product name:

`<input type='hidden' name='prodName' value='Product Name' />`

I use jquery to capture the form submission event. How can i access the value of the prodName attribute for each individual form. I have tried:

`$('.productForm input[name=thing]').val();`

which works fine, provided there is only one form on the page. How can i access the attribute for each form object?

** EDIT **

I should clarify, getting the details of every form isnt a problem, what i need is to get the value of the product from the specific form that was submitted. Essentially im looking for a way to create jquery object representing the specific form submitted. The problem i have is that the way im capturing the event at the moment:

`$('.productForm').submit(function(){...});`

is only capturing the details of the first form on the page, regardless of which form was actually submitted. What i want is for `$(this)` inside a the function to represent a specific form.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$('.productForm input[name=thing]').each(function()
{
   $(this).val();
});
```

The method documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Ha, there were always gonna be lots of quick answers.

Comment: You just `had` to write "try this" instead of "use" and put more extra spaces and new lines! :D

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('.productForm input[name=thing]').each(function(){

    var val = $(this).val();

})
```

Answer (score 1):

On form submit...

```
$(".productForm").submit(function(){
    //Form is submitted, handle it here...
    var productName = $("input[name='prodName']", this).val();

    //Do 'return false' if you want to stop form submission
});
```

or, loop through each form...

```
$(".productForm").each(function(){
    //Loops through forms and sticks the product name in productName
    var productName = $("input[name='prodName']", this).val();
});
```

or, loop through each form and make a list of product names...

```
var productNames = [];
$(".productForm").each(function(){
    //Loops through forms and sticks the product name in productName
    productNames.push( $("input[name='prodName']", this).val() );
});
//Now you have productNames which is now ["Apples", "Grapes", ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function to quickly *map* the values to an array

```
var products = $.map($(".productForm input[name='thing']"), function(n){
    return $(n).val();
});
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/KdNLL/